# Use local compiler flags in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` which imports several static libraries like so:

```
add_subdirectory("/foo/bar" "/bar/foo")
add_subdirectory("/foo2/bar" "/bar2/foo")
```

In my main `CMakeLists.txt` I set `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` like this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ...my flags...")
```

All static libraries which I import using `add_subdirectory` seem to inherit these flags as well now but I don't want that! Is there any way to set the compiler flags locally, i.e. just for the source files inside the respective `CMakeLists.txt` file instead of the whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command [add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_compile_options.html) sets compiler flags only for targets inside current `CMakeLists.txt` (and subdirectories):

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_subdirectory("foo/bar" "/bar/foo")
add_executable(main_exe ...) # Unaffected by 'add_compile_options' below.
```

**foo/bar/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# set flags for futher targets in current CMakeLists.txt
add_compile_options(<my_flags>)
add_executable(sub_exe ...) # Affected by 'add_compile_options' above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of CMake suggests to use target-specific commands, such as *target_include_directories*, *target_compile_options*, *target_compile_definitions*. These commands only affect specified target (and possibly the target's descendant users).

Please refer to [CMake-commands doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake-commands.7.html) for more details.